# Mover un Slider por pasos o segmentos

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Necesito crear un Slider que se mueva por pasos. En una escala de 0 a 100 unidades, que pueda moverse en 5 pasos de 20 unidades. He intentado hacerlo con la clase Slider que viene por defecto en Xcode.
Había pensado redondear el valor cuando moviera el Slider al paso siguiente, pero no funciona.

Actualmente tengo el código metido en un método IBAction que se llama cuando he movido el Slider de esta manera:

```
int paso = 100 / 5;
[slider setValue:roundf(slider.value/paso)*paso];
```

Comment: ¿El código se llega a ejecutar? ¿Qué valor tiene `slider.value`, y con qué valor queda el _slider_ después de hacerle el `setValue:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es simple. Haz un slider que vaya del `0.0` al `5.0` por ejemplo. Para redondear los pasos ejecuta el siguiente código:

```
func sliderEditingDidEnd(sender: UISlider) {

        // Ajustamos con animación suave
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            sender.setValue(round(sender.value), animated: true)
        })

}
```

Después, para obtener el valor, solo tendrás que hacer:

```
let valor = slider.value * 20.0
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo solucione.